# Calling a PHP function containing SQL query in separate PHP function building HTML table on separate page?

Tags: php, html

Basically, I'm trying to organize my code cleaner.  I have a bunch of SQL queries which I am storing in a file called Queries.PHP.  Example:

```
//Queries.php

//Connects to Database
$dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "~", "~") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("~") or ("Database not found");

function hi3() {
$query = "SELECT AVG(NULLIF(`~`, 0)) FROM `~` WHERE `~` BETWEEN '~' AND '~';";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "~";

}
```

Then, on a separate page, I have code that is building HTML table headers and a separate function building the contents:

```
include Queries.php;

function BuildHTMLTableHeaders {

echo HTML table headers;

BuildHTMLTableBody();

echo </table>;
}

function BuildHTMLBody {

echo <tr>;
echo <td>;
hi3();
echo </td>;
echo </tr>;
...

}
```

Now, here's my problem: when I call hi3(), the rest of the table doesn't build.  Why?

Comment: You forgot to the `while` loop. For example: `while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){}`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in BuildHTMLBody is flawed. You're only ever going to echo out 1 table row/cell because you're not looping through the results you get from your function.

```
function hi3() {
    $query = "SELECT AVG(NULLIF(`~`, 0)) FROM `~` WHERE `~` BETWEEN '~' AND '~';";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result.mysql_error());
    return $result;
}

function BuildHTMLBody {
    $rows = hi3();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['data'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Notice I return the results of hi3() and assign the results to a variable in BuildHTMLBody() and loop through them.

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure if there are any syntax errors. Also, I would suggest using mysqli_. mysql_ is deprecated.